# Overriding methods in TFMXViewBase in a Delphi iOS app

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey-fm3

Is there any way to override the methods in TFMXViewBase for an iOS form in Delphi?

Specifically I want to override TFMXViewBase.touchesBegan, TFMXViewBase.touchesEnded, TFMXViewBase.touchesMoved.

I am trying to avid having to modify the standard FMX.Platform.iOS unit

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's declared in the `implementation` section of `FMX.Platform.iOS.pas`, which means it's only visible inside that unit's implementation code below the point where it's declared. It's not exposed in any way that would allow it to be modified.

(You might want to ask a new question about what you're trying to accomplish that would require you to do this, BTW. There might be alternatives available that you actually *can* utilize, but it's difficult to say one way or the other with the extremely restricted scope you've provided here.)

Comment: Thanks I suspected this was the case. I have asked the question of what I am trying to achieve (getting multiple touch points) before and been chasing as answer for months. After a lot of investigation the last bit of the puzzle is extracting the event from TFMXViewBase. Looks like to will need to modify the unit.